# Manually acknowledge Kafka Batch listener. What I am doing wrong for multi-threading?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, executorservice, spring-kafka

I am creating an application which consumes data from kafka and does some processing on it. Since, the scale on which this app  should work is huge, I am using Concurrent Batch listener(max.poll.records = 20) with Java 8 Executor service. Below is the piece of code with comments where I am stuck:

```
    //Below method is invoked by spring kafka concurrent batch listener
public void onMessage(List<ConsumerRecord<String,String>> records , Acknowledgement ack)
{
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> records.stream().forEach(record -> 
    doSomeProcessingAsynchronously()),new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,10,0,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS. new 
    LinkedBlockingQueue<>(20)));
    //I want to execute all consumed records first only then flow should come after this line
    //and acknowledge complete batch
    ack.acknowledge();
}
```

Any suggestion on how to get this done ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(records.size());
```

then within the lambda count it down for each completed task.

Before acknowledging `boolean ok = latch.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`.

(check for a timeout and act appropriately).

> `records.stream().forEach(...`

That said, you are not running the processing in parallel; you are simply running all 20 sequentially on a different thread.

You need to move the forEach outside.

Comment: Note that you are not currently running in parallel - just running them all sequentially on a different thread.

Comment: Thanks @Gary Russel